# Javascript Onclick Issue

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I can't get this to work. Dropping the JavaScript directly onto the *onclick* event works fine, but it *doesn't* this way.

**JavaScript**

```
function checkid(objDivID) {
    if(this.id == 'id1') {
        alert('ID is Checked') 
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr id='id". $row['id'] ."' class='rrtr' onclick=\"checkid(this.id);\">
    <td class='name'>". $row['name'] ."</td>
    <td class='data'>". $row['TotalResp'] ."</td>
    <td class='data'>". $row['StaffCount'] ."</td>
    <td class='data'><b>". number_format($row['Perc'],0) ."</b></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks, H.

Comment: What is the problem? The function never fires?

Comment: Solved - I was using this.id instead of objDivID in the Java statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the function `this.id`, but then in the function you try to reference that again. It won't work. Use the parameter name instead.

```
function checkid(objDivID){
    if(objDivID == 'id1'){alert('ID is Checked')};
}
```

Also the backslashes quoting the double-quotes in the HTML are probably not really there, right? You're printing that HTML as a string I presume.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by several ways, one is calling function specifying `this`:

```
<tr id='id". $row['id'] ."' class='rrtr' onclick=\"checkid.call(this, this.id);\">
```

Or just use passed id:

```
function checkid(objDivID){
    if(objDivID == 'id1'){alert('ID is Checked')};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using `this` in the wrong scope. Change the line

```
if(this.id == 'id1'){alert('ID is Checked')};
```

to

```
if(objDivID == 'id1'){alert('ID is Checked')};
```